# Some remote image is not showing in react native iOS but showing in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

Some remote image is not showing in react native iOS. But the same image is showing in android.

This is not happening for all images.

***Not showing:*** https://d1ldvf68ux039x.cloudfront.net/thumbs/frames/audio/2211/71371/122x92_q95.jpg

***Showing:*** https://d1ldvf68ux039x.cloudfront.net/thumbs/frames/audio/2211/71249/122x92_q95.jpg

```js
<Image
  resizeMode={'contain'}
  style={{width: 140, height: 140, borderRadius: 5}}
  source={{uri: "https://d1ldvf68ux039x.cloudfront.net/thumbs/frames/audio/2211/71371/122x92_q95.jpg"}}
/>
```